# More efficient way of targeting child element on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-datepicker

In many cases, I use jQuery's awesome [datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) in forms. I wanted a generic way to apply it without knowing what the id or class of the input would be. I came up with this:

```
<span id="datePickerChild">
 <input type="text"/>
</span>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document.getElementById("datePickerChild").firstChild).datepicker();
</script>
```

Using the mvc3 framework these inputs get put in with their own ids and such at runtime based on the helpers so I wanted this dynamic approach. Is there a more efficient way to be doing this?

Edit:

Using jQuery 1.4.4

Comment: That will work, however it will only work for a single element. ID's must be unique.

Comment: just do `$("#datePickerChild:first").datepicker();`

Comment: That solution certainly looks like you know _an_ ID or class name, so I fail to see how this is better than simply assigning datepicker off a class name.

Comment: @KevinB - I agree, however, there are no instances where I am entering multiple dates in one page.

Comment: @mgraph - Sorry for not stating this first, but I am using jQuery 1.4.4 and I do not think it supports that type of selection.

Comment: @Tejs - You mean attach an event to the page load and then have it put datepicker on the child of every class named datePickerChild?

Comment: @TravisJ you can do :`$("#datePickerChild").eq(0).datepicker();`

Comment: I mean that I don't get the purpose of your code; it would seem to be _way_ simpler to write `$('.someClass').datepicker()` and make those elements datepickers, than it is to make a complicated relationship traversal to assign a datepicker.

Comment: @Tejs - It would, but I dont have access to that element as it is produced from a razor helper - `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateEntry)`

Comment: The editor template for that property can easily provide a class name or other identifier on the element then. This seems to be a workaround instead of a solution.

Comment: @Tejs - With `, new { class = "datepickerClass" }`. You are right, not sure why I didn't think of that. Thanks!

Comment: @Tejs - Turns out that is non trivial and you cannot append a class in that fashion without extending the `Html.EditorFor`. It forces you to use `Html.TextBoxFor` which wont work in an editor situation. In the end, I went with the first approach detailed in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems like a reasonable approach for this.  You could probably do it a little more "idiomatically" with jQuery like the following:

```
$('#datePickerChild').children().first().datepicker();
```

Or even:

```
$('#datePickerChild > input:first').datepicker();
```

One point of confusion, however, is that you say you want to do this without having to know what the id of the element is, although you still use an id in the selector.  If you're trying to use that id "generically" (as in it appears several times on the page), you would want to use a class instead.  Once you have a class on the element you need, you would just change your selector to something like:

```
$('.date-picker-container').children().first().datepicker();
```

Comment: Yes. (and filler to make this comment long enough to post :)

Comment: Although, to be honest, I would go with the `.children()` approach. jQuery uses a right-to-left query engine, so it will be more efficient to select something using a cheap approach (like id or class name), and then drill down.

Comment: Of the approaches taken, your suggestion of using `.children()` is what I ended up using.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so based on your comments saying you don't know the *exact* ID and you don't want to use classes, can't you just do a partial ID match that would match all of them? Something like:

```
$("[id*=datePicker]").datepicker();
```

Comment: I am not against using class names, it is just that in my situation there is only one occurance per page of a date needing to be chosen.

Comment: Be careful with this - it will literally crawl every node in the DOM because it has to check each one for an id attribute, and then perform a regular expression against it if present.

Comment: @jmar777 so would selecting on a class? It's going to have to crawl the DOM to find elements with that class?

Comment: Only in very old browsers - newer browsers have stuff like `getElementsByClassName` (or even `querySelectorAll`).

Comment: @TravisJ even if there's only one occurrence, you're still better off using a class really as then you don't have to do any fuzzy matching on any other properties :)

Comment: @jmar777 Fair point, but is it really *that* expensive to be doing this? I would have suggested classes had he not said no to it on the comments to the question :)

Comment: @mattytommo Ahh, I missed his comment there. If he knows that the `datePicker` element is always going to be a div, your solution could be made a little more efficient by doing `$('div[id*=datePicker]')` - at least that will let the query engine (sizzle) use `getElementsByTagName` under the hood. In general you just want to minimize the amount of DOM traversal necessary. JavaScript is fast, but the DOM is sloooow.